# ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug' when using exoplayer and jwplayer at a time

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, jwplayer, exoplayer

I am using both exoplayer and jwplayer in my project.
exoplayer- to play encrypted videos
jwplayer - to play video from link

but when I am using the both libraries in build gradle I am getting the below error.

```
:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug UP-TO-DATE
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.dash.BuildConfig","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED
:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\43.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\51.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\52.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\54.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\55.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\56.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\62.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\63.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\64.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\66.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\68.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\69.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\70.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\71.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\74.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\75.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\76.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\77.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\78.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\79.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\80.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\81.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\82.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\85.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\86.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\87.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\88.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\103.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\104.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\105.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\106.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\107.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\108.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\109.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\115.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\116.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\117.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\118.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\119.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\120.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\121.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\122.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\123.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\124.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\125.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\126.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\127.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\128.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\129.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\130.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\131.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\132.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\133.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\134.jar, C:\Users\Aadhhan\Bitbucket\Hixic New\Hixic Version Mar-2018\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\135.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
60 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 51 up-to-date
```

here is my app build gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'

        exclude 'error_prone/Annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Annotations.gwt.xml'
    exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Google_internal.gwt.xml'
    exclude 'jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml'

}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.aadhan.videos"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            includeCompileClasspath = true
        }
    }

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }


}
dexOptions {
    // Prevent OutOfMemory with MultiDex during the build phase
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    preDexLibraries = true
}
}
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
//constraint
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation project(':supportapp')
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-core:+'
implementation 'com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-common:+'
// Only required if using IMA features
implementation 'com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-ima:+'
// Only required if using Chromecast jh
implementation 'com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-chromecast:+'


implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation files('libs/httpclient-4.2.3.jar')
implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.10'
// Facebook Login only
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.28.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.28.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
// glide
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.7.2'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

sorry from my poor english, this is my first post. please help me out with the solution

Comment: Try to use a hard-coded value for the jwplayer version, not `+`., I guess there's a collusion between some of your dependencies. You can also try this to see if this is the case: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: I have already enabled multidex but no use. Recent version of jwplayer has exoplayer dependency thats why it is not working. can you please suggest me a working solution @HedShafran

Answer (score 0):

To anyone coming from google, this happened to me when Android Studio tried to automatically import `implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'` when I already had defined `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'` in the `build.gradle`. There's a conflict in those 2 libraries.